# Hover effect on product when loading the page

Tags: css, hover

I have some issues on my website with a hover effect.

When I load a collection and then go very quickly on a product, the hover effect glitches, and if I go to another product it shows the effect twice ([hover bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H408D.png))

When I leave the mouse on a product when it's loading it gives me this result.

Here is my code:

```
.hoverbuttons {display:none}
.quickbutton {display:block}

.hovereffect {margin-top: -38px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);;
    border-top: 0px solid {{settings.border_color}};
    transition: all .7s ease-in;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-delay: initial;

}

.hoverthumb {box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.15);}

.thumbnail {height:295px}

.formbkg{background-color:white;border:1px solid {{settings.productformborder}};padding: 10px;}

.swatch .swatch-element {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem but you have a double ;; in this line

```
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);;
```

This would prevent the rest of your transitions/stylings from being used. Otherwise, it's hard to see exactly what's going on here without your HTML, but I would try playing with your transition lengths and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you catch22 I remove the double; Will play with the transitions